# Joomla Chronoforms working when logged in but not when browsing as a guest

Tags: joomla, mootools, chronoforms

I decided to ask this question here because this might not be completely Chronoforms-plugin related. My problem is that I've made a custom Joomla registration form with Chronoforms, but when I'm trying to submit it, the page just refreshes. In fact none of the forms made by Chronoforms aren't working if I'm not logged in. But if I am, they are all working just fine.

My guess is that this has something to do with Mootools, as Chronoforms is using Mootools and when I log in, the site seems to be loading Mootools so that the forms work. But I don't know how could I troubleshoot this... Here's the link to the registration form: http://tylypahka.tk/muuta/rekisteroidy

Any suggestions and help will be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you get this working? Please tag Mootools also when you post if you think the problem (still) lies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- try temporarily setting site Error Reporting to Maximum to see if there are any meaningful error messages
- try temporarily enabling debug
- if using ChronoForms v4, try setting Relative URL to No in the form
  General tab
- if using CAPTCHA with cache enabled, try with cache disabled
- if using CAPTCHA, try temporarily disabling CAPTCHA or try RECAPTCHA instead

Reference: http://chronoengine.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=65518&p=311707&hilit=form+not+submitting#p264431

Comment: Thanks, although I already solved the problem this is an excellent answer. The problem indeed was with caching and I got it working by disabling cache. Anyway thanks for replying to such and old question, I forgot to post my own solution back then.

Comment: @Ilari, thanks, you decision helped me too. But could you find any solutions to turn cache on?